# Android Switch set thumbResource programmatically

Tags: android

I need to add customised Switch to my application. I know that usually to display it in a way you like you need to create a selector for thumb and track resources and set it in the XML, which I did and it works. Code for selectors is as follows:
1. thumb_selector.xml

`<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_thumb_disabled" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_thumb_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_thumb_activated" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_thumb"/>
</selector>`

1. bg_selector.xml

   `<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_bg_disabled" android:state_enabled="false"/>
       <item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_bg_focused" android:state_focused="true"/>
       <item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_bg_on" android:state_checked="true"/>
       <item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_bg"/>
   </selector>`

These selectors are located in drawable resource folder, so when I use

```
android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_selector"
android:track="@drawable/bg_selector"
```

switch is displayed as expected. However, there are other properties and many Views I have to create dynamically, so it is better to add a custom control (which extends Switch), and I need to set ThumbResource and TrackResource. Documentation says there are two methods, which can set it: [setThumbResource(int resId)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html#setThumbResource%28int%29) and [setTrackResource(int resId)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html#setTrackResource%28int%29), but when I try to reference selector as `setThumbResource(R.drawable.thumb_selector)` it doesn't recognise this selector as drawable. It's a silly problem and I can't seem to be able to solve it, did I add it to the wrong folder? One way to work around this is to extend layout and inflate xml version of Switch, but do I have to do this? How can I reference selector within the code?

Comment: Your code looks reasonable. I'm also doing 
     selectSwitch.setThumbResource(R.drawable.custom_drawable_resource);  and my custom_drawable_resource.xml which is located in the res/drawable folder is recognized as a valid resource.